# Local laravel project redirects to live site

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I think I have a pretty dumb question, but I can't find an answer!

When I want to visit my laravel project on my local machine (at 192.168.33.10) it redirects me to the live site (www.google.be)

I tried googling for a solution since I think it's just a simple .env setting, but no luck yet

here's my .env file.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=foodtruck
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: check your `host` file

Comment: What's your laravel project URL on the local machine?

Comment: @ArtyomSokolov it's 192.168.33.10

Comment: Well, I suspect there's something wrong with your browser settings. I would try to type full URL in your browser address box, including http:// part. For example, `http://192.168.33.10`

Comment: Found out the problem, my collegue had changed some of .htaccess files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your htaccess

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the htaccess file, See the give below code in your htaccess file:

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abcd.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Replace https://abcd.com to your localhost URL Like this

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/example/$1 [R,L]
```

I hope your problem will be solved, if not solved try another method:
Goes to your .env file

Change the APP_UR to your localhost URL like this:

```
  APP_URL=http://localhost/Abbasi_27
  and make sure APP_DEBUG=true
```

if not solved your problem then try the next method:
Goes to config/app.php

make the changes in the app.php file:

Change the URL and Asset_url to your localhost URL like this

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/example'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'http://localhost/example'),
```

I hope your problem will be solved. Thanks.